# Playing video instead of splash screen when application starts in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, splash-screen

this question is asked many times by different people in different ways, but My question is can anybody help me in providing me with the sample code because i can't find in any of the answered questions in any forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do its put a viewController that first load and play the video and while the video it's loading you can load in background the others viewControllers